# Using If else to compare Mac Address in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, scripting, conditional-statements

This is my following Code. I keep getting the error "Try again" even though my Mac Address is same. I somehow want to execute Exec.bat if the condition is true. [By the way MacCheck.txt has my Mac address as 08-3E-8E-2C-DF-F7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOU1b.png)

```
@ echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set content=
for /F "delims=" %%i in (MacCheck.txt) do set content=!content! %%i
rem %content%
SET Mac="08-3E-8E-2C-DF-F7 "
if  "content" == "Mac" (start Exec.bat) else (echo "Try again") 
EndLocal
pause
```

Comment: comparing two different strings will not help you. You have to compare variables: `if  "%content%" == "%Mac%" ...`

Comment: change `"content" == "Mac"` to `"%content%" == "%Mac%"`

Comment: Thank you brother but now my Exec.bat that displays Hello World is not executing.No cmd pop up displays hello world. Is that beacuse of pause keyword in my script ?? The output now is "Press any key to continue". Thats all

Comment: You haven't shown us `exec.bat`. Since you are `start`ing it, it will (or should) create a new window. You would need a `pause` command to make that window visible if all `exec.bat` does is to show the message and exit. The `press key...` is the normal prompt from `pause` to wait until the user presses a key.

Comment: maybe `call Exec.bat` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run only on a special machine with given MAC, don't use a file but the program `GetMac.exe` and check against the given MAC-address.

```
@Echo off
Getmac.exe | find /i "08-3E-8E-2C-DF-F7" && (start Exec.bat) || (Echo whatever&Pause)
```

This uses conditional execution on succes `&&` aka found or fail `||`

Comment: I know ;-) Vote up and/or check the grey mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Should you wish to use the discovered MAC as a variable elsewhere in the code you could try:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "TargetMAC=08-3E-8E-2C-DF-F7"
For /F Delims^=^" %%A In ('GetMAC /FO CSV /NH') Do Set "MyMAC=%%A"
If /I "%TargetMAC%"=="%MyMAC%" (Call "Exec.bat") Else Echo "Try again" 
Pause
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: As previously mentioned by LotPings, the best way to show your thanks is to mark one answer as your chosen solution.